# Get blogger latest post link using php xml

Tags: php, xml

I am using the code below. This code is showing me title, time and content, not showing me post link. Also I want to show the latest update post link but this is not showing me link.

check this code please.

```
<?php
$file="https://*******.blogspot.com/atom.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
foreach ( $xml->entry as $foo ) {
    echo '<h2>' . $foo->title . '</h2>';
    echo '<p>' . $foo->updated . '</p>';
    echo '<p>' . $foo->content . '</p>';
    foreach ( $foo->link as $link ) {
        $type = (string) $link->attributes()->{'type'};
        if ( $type == 'text/html' ) {
            echo (string) $link->attributes()->{'title'};;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the attributes of an element as though it is an array, so your code should look like...

```
foreach ( $foo->link as $link ) {
    $type = (string) $link['type'];
    if ( $type == 'text/html' ) {
        echo (string) $link['title'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code only had the title in it, if this is the href from the link element, then  `(string)$link['href']`.